# Access variable defined in a protected function in the same class

Tags: php, function

Hi,

I have this code:

```
class ssi
{
 protected function _example1() {
  $somevar = "hello";
 }

 protected function _example2() {
  $newvar = $somevar;
 }
}
```

I want to access $somevar from within function example2() but without having to do this:

```
$newvar = example1();
```

Is it possible? I tried with the code below but didnt work:

```
$newvar = $this->_example1()->$somevar;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, that variable only exists within that function (also called a method when it's part of a class). What you need to do is make it a class property and then access it from within the methods using the `$this` keyword like this:

```
class ssi
{
 protected $somvar = "hello";
 protected function _example1() {
  $this->somevar .= " world";;
 }

 protected function _example2() {
  $newvar = $this->somevar;
 }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code but I dont get any value. that double ;; is no typo?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to [scoping rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  The specific rule this violates is mentioned this way in the manual:

> [W]ithin user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

Access to that local variable is lost the moment that function returns from being called.  This works similarly in PHP as in pretty much every single language I am aware of.

If you need data to come out of that function, then you should *return* it:

```
class ssi
{
    protected function _example1() 
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    protected function _example2() 
    {
        $newval = $this->_example1();
    }
}
```

Or, set a class property that can be accessed from other functions:

```
class ssi
{
    protected $somevar;
    protected function _example1() 
    {
        $this->somvar = "hello";
    }

    protected function _example2() 
    {
        // Note you still need to actually call the function first
        $this->_example1();
        $newvar = $this->somevar;
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can imagine anything being returned from a function as replacing the actual function call with the results of calling that function.

```
function adder($n) {
    return $n + 1;
}

$test = adder(5);
```

In this example, you would expect for `$test` to equal 6 (which it will).  However, after the call to `adder` returns, the parameter `$n` is no longer accessible, so any attempt to reference that variable will fail.

I think what Styphon was alluding to in his comment was something along these lines:

```
function iReturnAnObject() {
    $value = new StdClass;
    $value->somevar = "hello";
    return $value;
}

$test = iReturnAnObject()->somevar;
```

This code will work, and `$test` will hold the value `"hello"` after executing.

Comment: what about $newvar = $this->_example1()->somevar;

Comment: @CainNuke You just can't do that. For that code to work `_example1()` would have to return another object that contained `somevar`.

Comment: another object? like what?

Comment: @CainNuke I have updated the answer with another example

Comment: in that last example, can it work also for protected functions?

Comment: @CainNuke all `protected`, `private` and `public` do is dictate _where_ they can be called from. If you're calling this code from within the same class (or any subclass), then yes it will work.